# How to use 'on change' event on an input type hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Demo and full code is like this :

http://jsfiddle.net/9R4cV/685/

I using like this :

```
$('#customer').on('change', function() {
    $('#customer_copy').val($(this).val());
});
```

But it's not working

Any solution to solve my problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no attempt at a problem description.

Comment: You don't have `#customer_name` element in your markup.

Comment: Programmatically changing a value of an input (hidden or otherwise) does not raise an event - you need to do it manually `trigger('change')` for example

Comment: @PeeHaa, Of questions and my code, like its already inadequate to describe my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to trigger `.change()` (*or `.trigger('change')`*) on input value changes, otherwise programatically changes are not triggering events.
2. The `id` of your input is `#customer` not `#customer_name`.

---

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: aTags,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $("#customer").val(ui.item.label).change();
    }
});

$('#customer').on('change', function() {
    $('#customer_copy').val($(this).val());
});
```

**[Working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/9R4cV/691/)**

Answer (score -1):

Why not change the `#customer_copy` directly when item selected?

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: aTags,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            console.log(ui.item.label);
            $("#customer").val(ui.item.label);
            $("#customer_copy").val(ui.item.label)
        }
    });
```